# Loading JSON image Fast

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

I am developing an iOS App. And fetch images through JSON and show on tableview. Using this method `dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{...` and image show on table view but all image show on one cell and automatically recycling. Image can be change after some time and also using the placeholder image. To Show Image using two string one string Can use for image name and second string can be use for URL. Then concat the string to show image thats same problem in collection view. Any other method to show image fast in tableview and collection view.
My code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    {
        mycell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
        UILabel *mylabel = (UILabel *)[mycell viewWithTag:100];
        NSDictionary *dic=[str objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        GRLanguage *sharedManager = [GRLanguage sharedManager];
        if ([sharedManager.LanguageCode isEqual:@"hi"]) {
            mylabel.text=[dic objectForKey:@"hindi_name"];
        }else if ([sharedManager.LanguageCode isEqual:@"pa"])
        {
            mylabel.text=[dic objectForKey:@"punjabi_name"];
        }else
        {
            mylabel.text=[dic objectForKey:@"name"];
        }


        [mycell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back copy.png"]];
        self.tableview.backgroundView =img;


        dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{     //Using For Lazy Loading
            UIImageView *imagetlt = (UIImageView *)[mycell viewWithTag:1];
            NSString *image =[dic objectForKey:@"image_path"];
            NSString *path=@"http://webapp.opaxweb.net/images/";
            path=[path stringByAppendingString:image];
            NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
            if (image == nil) {
                 [imagetlt setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rel_circle.png"]];
            }else
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                  //  UITableViewCell*img = (id) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                    imagetlt.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
                });

            }


    });
     return mycell;
}
```

Comment: Suggestion - AsyncImageLoader in GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

You have a severe problem. You create a cell, then you try to load an image asynchrously and try to store it in the cell. That cannot work. Cells will be reused. By the time the image arrives, the cell may be displaying completely different data.

Here's what you do: You keep images returned from URLs cached in memory or stored in files. In cellForRowAtIndexPath you try retrieving a cached image and store that, or you store a placeholder image and start the asynchronous download. When the download finishes, you put the image into your cache and call reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: so that the row will be reloaded.

What's even better, if items can change their row while the asynchronous download is running (because the user adds or deletes rows, or sorting order is changed and so on), when the asynchronous download ends, you figure out which row contains that item (which might not be the row containing it when the download started), and call reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: for that row.